# How can I create this type of navigation using bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

[I need something like this type of navigation functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlmJ8.png)

HERE IS BRIEF:
After open website search icon will be showing and after click on search icon, there will have "X" icon appear with fade from right nav links appear.

Can you please tell me how can I do this?

Waiting for quick solution.

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: I don't have any code. I want to create this from scratch.

Comment: Please help me. It is really essential for me.